# What is the Haskell equivalence of Rust's associated types?

Tags: haskell, generics, type-systems

What is the Haskell equivalence of Rust's [associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/assoc_items/types.html)?

Comment: I'm not very experienced with Rust, but its associated types sure look a lot like [associated type families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Associated_family_declarations_2), no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haskell has [associated type families](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/type_families.html#associated-data-and-type-families). The `Contains` example on the linked page can be written in Haskell like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class Contains a where
  type A a
  type B a
  contains :: a -> A a -> B a -> Bool

data Container = MkContainer Int Int

instance Contains Container where
  type A Container = Int
  type B Container = Int
  contains (MkContainer x y) a b = x == a && y == b
```